# Trying to import Tiff files created in arc9.3 into 10.2, not working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system, arcgis-9.3, geotiff-tiff

I'm trying to use the scanned maps available here: http://www.env.gov.bc.ca/esd/distdata/ecosystems/TEI_Scanned_Maps/B01/B01-4700/

I save all 6 files in a folder, open ArcGIS 10.2 and try to add to my data frame from the catalogue. I can view the tiff but it will not georeference. Warning shows "Unknown Spatial Reference". This should be embedded in the provided files but are not being accessed properly.

Can someone try to import the files from the link above and let me know if they can get them to properly georeference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I downloaded 2 files B01-4700.tiff and B01-4700.TFwx.
- renamed B01-4700.TFWx into B01-4700.TFw
- defined projection as GCS_WGS_1984

RESULT:
[image]

Comment: Note they are slightly off